# What is the name of the matrix with zeros everywhere except along first row, first column, and main diagonal?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I remember there's a name for this matrix but I can't find it on google. Here's an example:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 8 & 23 \\
6 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that only the locations with a 0 are guaranteed to be 0. The first row, column, and main diagonal can be non-zero or zero

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix too short for an answer